# Acho que minha tabela não está sendo criada : no such table?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

EStou tentando fazer uma verificação para saber se existe algo inserido na tabela, mas ele sempre da erro nesta linha dizendo que nao existe tal tabela.

meu banco de dados:

```
package comviewzonazul.google.httpssites.zonazul.infraestrutura;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String BANCO_DADOS = "tasks";
    private static final int VERSAO = 1;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, BANCO_DADOS, null, VERSAO);
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return BANCO_DADOS;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Tabela de usuarios
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Usuarios ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "nome TEXT, login TEXT, senha TEXT)");
        // Tabela de clientes
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Clientes ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "saldo TEXT, usuario TEXT, email TEXT, cep TEXT, complemento TEXT, numero TEXT, cidade TEXT, id_usuario TEXT)");
        //Cadastrar um usuario
        db.execSQL("insert into Usuarios(nome, login, senha) values('Admin', 'admin','123')");
        //Associações
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Perfis ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "usuario TEXT, perfil TEXT)");
        //tabela carros
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Carros(id iINTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "fabricante TEXT, modelo TEXT, cor TEXT, ano TEXT, placa TEXT)");
        // Tabela de compras
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Compra ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "tipo TEXT, valor TEXT, id_comprador TEXT, data TEXT)");
        // Tabela de carro para cliente
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CarroCliente ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "cliente TEXT, carro TEXT)");



    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public static class Usuarios {
        public static final String TABELA = "usuarios";
        public static final String _ID = "_id";
        public static final String NOME = "nome";
        public static final String LOGIN = "login";
        public static final String SENHA = "senha";
        public static final String[] COLUNAS = new String[]{
                _ID, NOME, LOGIN, SENHA
        };
    }

    public static class Clientes {
        public static final String TABELA_CLIENTES = "clientes";
        public static final String _ID = "_id";
        public static final String SALDO = "saldo";
        public static final String USUARIO = "usuario";
        public static final String EMAIL = "email";
        public static final String CEP = "cep";
        public static final String COMPLEMENTO = "complemento";
        public static final String NUMERO = "numero";
        public static final String CIDADE = "cidade";
        public static final String[] COLUNAS_CLIENTES = new String[]{
                _ID, SALDO, USUARIO, EMAIL, CEP, COMPLEMENTO, NUMERO, CIDADE,
        };
    }

    public static class Perfis {
        public static final String TABELA_PERFIS = "perfis";
        public static final String ID = "id";
        public static final String ID_USUARIO = "usuario";
        public static final String ID_PERFIL = "perfil";
        public static final String[] COLUNAS_PERFIS = new String[]{
                ID, ID_USUARIO, ID_PERFIL,
        };
    }
    public static class CarroCliente {
        public static final String TABELA_CARROCLIENTE = "carroCliente";
        public static final String ID = "id";
        public static final String ID_CLIENTE = "cliente";
        public static final String ID_CARRO = "carro";
        public static final String[] COLUNAS_CARROCLIENTE = new String[]{
                ID, ID_CLIENTE, ID_CARRO,
        };
    }
    public static class Carros {
        public static final String TABELA_CARROS = "carros";
        public static final String ID = "id";
        public static final String FABRICANTE = "fabricante";
        public static final String MODELO = "modelo";
        public static final String COR = "cor";
        public static final String ANO = "ano";
        public static final String PLACA = "placa";
        public static final String[] COLUNAS_CARRO = new String[]{
                ID, FABRICANTE, MODELO, COR, PLACA
        };
    }

    public static class Compra {
        public static final String TABELA_COMPRA = "compra";
        public static final String ID = "_id";
        public static final String TIPO = "tipo";
        public static final String VALOR = "valor";
        public static final String ID_COMPRADOR = "id_comprador";
        public static final String DATA = "data";
        public static final String[] COLUNAS_COMPRA = new String[]{
                ID, TIPO, VALOR, ID_COMPRADOR, DATA
        };
    }
}
```

Minha função para buscar no banco:

```
public String retornarPlaca(String placa){ //Informa se exites ou não uma placa ja cadastrada
        Cursor cursor = getDatabase().query(DatabaseHelper.Carros.TABELA_CARROS, DatabaseHelper.Carros.COLUNAS_CARRO, DatabaseHelper.Carros.PLACA+"=?", new String[]{placa}, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() !=0){
            return placa;

        }
        return null;
    }
```

O erro da na linha que inicia o cursor.

Answer (score 0):

A sua variável `Carros.TABELA_CARROS` tem valor "carros" e a tabela que você cria se chama "Carros".

Por que você não usa essas constantes nas strings de criações das tabelas e colunas? Evita esse tipo de problema.

Ex:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + Carros.TABELA_CARROS + 
"(" + Carros.ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + ...
```